# Are there any legitimate reasons for adding more than one answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, multiple-answers

Sometimes, but rarely, when I post an answer that turns out to be incorrect and it makes more sense to just start over, I delete it and re-post a second. Of course, the first is still there, although it's deleted.

Other than something like that, though, are there acceptable reasons for adding more than one answer to a question?

Comment: I'd do this If i was downvoted for being wrong and fixing it would take long enough that it'd be downvoted to oblivion

Comment: @Cole but once you realized what was wrong, you could delete the question, edit it, then undelete it. Posting a second, different answer (even if you deleted the first) leaves a bunch of extra baggage on the question that 10K/mods have to look at every time.

Comment: Also related: [A second try at a question with a second answer rather than editing the first one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52404)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought we couldn't edit our deleted posts?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I can definitely edit deleted questions. I just tried it now on SO.

Comment: @Cole did you try it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand no, because I've never been in a situation like what I described

Comment: @ColeJohnson Ha. It's tough never being wrong, isn't it? :)

Comment: @JasonC I know. I still dream of the day I become Jon Skeet ;)

Comment: @ColeJohnson http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/3160/jon-skeet-comparison

Comment: @JasonC I got a 1 and Skeet got a 6 :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do this with some regularity.  If each answer provides a distinct method it is arguable that separating them allows the community to vote for the one that is better rather than voting for an omnibus answer.

Of course this could easily be overused and *most* of the time I post a single answer with multiple options.  I try to reserve posting two answers for cases where the approach is starkly different.

Comment: And now I notice that this question is apparently a duplicate. :-/

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about this. I'd say that questions where a person can post two completely separate answers with different solutions, but each answer still be correct and useful, are probably not acceptable questions for Stack Exchange sites. That is, they are probably polls, or have underspecified requirements.

Comment: @Cody I don't agree with that. In SQL Server, for example, there are many ways to do something, and some of them work better on (or require) a specific version, some work better on (or require) a different edition, etc. It's not something I ever do but I don't think this scenario automatically makes the question unacceptable.

Comment: @CodyGray As respectfully as is possible for this to be: I have no idea what you're talking about.  Beta sites are encouraged to have more than 2.5 answers per question.  Many if not *most* questions can have more than one reasonable answer.  Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: I have no idea why that is. The questions we're looking for tend to have one, possibly two, answer at most.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard right, if two people can post two completely separate answers, and both are valid ways to do something, why can't one person do that?

Comment: @CodyGray I'm sorry but you have an impoverished perspective on this.  Come over to [Mathematica.SE] some time and you'll see that it is quite possible for a question to have half a dozen *good* answers.  (If course that is the exception but I stand by my claim.)

Comment: @Cody I think that's a very bizarre limitation and not a very well-publicized goal if it is in fact part of the mission of this site. While the goal for one specific OP is to have a "best" answer, there is no requirement that they choose one, and different answers can be better for different future readers in different circumstances.

Comment: I do think I see where Cody is coming from, which relates to a comment I just made on John's answer here. SO tends to reject questions that don't have concrete answers (not because they're bad, but because I guess that's what SO goes for). If a question has two completely different answers that might be an indication that the question was too broad. When I have two (or more) different answers I usually post them as one and outline the differences. I can see how two answers might make separating upvotes easier, but you lose some ability to write out a comparison.

Comment: I don't agree that the fact that a question has multiple potential answers means it is too broad. Can you really say, with a straight face, that every programming problem can only be solved in one way? If that were the case, maybe we should consider only allowing one answer per question, period?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no, I'm asserting that it *is* a fact that there *are* valid questions with multiple potential solutions (and sometimes the same person might even dream up these multiple solutions on their own). I don't agree that the fact that such questions exist "might be an indication that the question was too broad." Not sure if that my line of thinking any clearer, but it's the best I can do. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can say (with a straight face) that almost every programming problem can be solved with a bit of analysis, sane judgment, and some common sense. The vast majority of questions that I see on SO relate to the asker having difficulty, in one form or another, translating the concept they have in their head to whatever language they are programming in. There may be very different *specific* solutions, but generally the same thought process is required to arrive at each, and that process is the real right answer. But, I'm 100% aware of how unpopular my "unified theory" of things is.

Comment: @JasonC but are you implying that two different people can't come to different answers even if they've both employed analysis, sane judgment, and some common sense? I don't always agree with the experts in my field, and we often solve problems in different ways, but that doesn't make one of us more right than the other. Many ways to skin a cat, and all that...

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's not *quite* what I'm saying. There's only one way to skin a cat: Step 1: Recognize that your goal is to remove the skin from the cat. Step 2: Start with the capabilities of the tools you have at your disposal and identify a path that takes you from cat with skin to cat without skin using those tools. Sure the specifics will be different, but the process of arriving at a method to skin the cat is essentially the same for each. How do I use what I have to do what I want in the most precise way possible? I kind of just want to write that as the answer to every SO question.

Comment: Actually, I want to amend that. There is a second way to skin a cat, which is purely by accident. Let's keep this constrained to the case where you actually *want* to remove the skin from a cat. Incidentally, I find it amusing that everybody assumes that the saying "there are many ways to skin a cat" is implicitly followed by "on purpose".

Comment: @JasonC but you're ignoring the fact that specifics *are* important and also that users might not know about a wide variety of tools they *might* have at their disposal. For example, if someone is trying to make their SQL Server database application more highly available, so that folks generating reports do not block the OLTP side of the business, there are many ways to make the data available to them without the blocking - from enabling RCSI to log shipping to replication to mirroring to availability groups - most appropriate might depend on budget, edition being used, expertise in house, etc

Comment: @JasonC Let's make this a little more humane. People don't come to Stack Overflow to get people to tell them the general process of arriving at a method to *shave* their cat. They want to know how. However, some people might prefer electric clippers (for very specific reasons), and others might prefer a straight razor (for different reasons). Is there still only one valid answer? Shouldn't we want to present the asker with as many options as possible, and as much information about those answers as possible? Why the need to categorize problems such that they only have one possible answer?

Comment: I am not a cat person, by the way. I just don't know enough about skinning them to make my example more concrete.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Re: Your first comment. All good points. Personally, I look at budget, edition being used, expertise in house, even personal preference and the ability to come to SO to ask a question all as tools that can be used to get to the goal. Re: Your second comment, well, one unified answer there may be "use whichever type of razor makes it easiest for you to shave your cat, which may just boil down to whichever one you prefer". Rather than try to convince somebody why one is better than the other, give them the knowledge they need to make that decision themselves.

Comment: I am totally a cat person, by the way. (And yes, I prefer the ones with skin.)

Comment: They could get a generic answer like "Whichever makes it easiest for you" from a psychic hotline or their senile grandmother or Stuart Smalley. I don't think making an answer that general (and useless, to boot, IMHO) is a strong case for there being only one answer. People come here to get *specific* answers, with technical justifications, downsides, etc., not for one person to tell them "do what you feel like."

Comment: @JasonC I don't think it is reasonable to expect that one person answering a question should be the designated person to outline all of the OP's potential options. Rather, what you'll find in the real world, is that one person very strong in replication will post an answer talking about that, and another who really likes log shipping will propose that instead. What you seem to be looking for is some kind of FAQ or canonical answer, and frankly those aren't useful to provide *an* answer to a *specific* problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't agree fully (nor do I disagree), but that's also very valid. Thinking about it more, I realize this comes from the types of questions I gravitate towards answering (on SO and elsewhere). Many people, especially inexperienced people, tend to ask questions like "I heard X is bad so I want to do Y" or "I want to use A to do B but it isn't working". My answers are usually along the lines of "This is why X might be bad, this is why X might be good, use the right tool for the job" or "Instead of thinking I want to use A to do B, just think I want to do B".

Comment: @JasonC further, if one of these "unified" answers contains one very good suggestion, and one terrible suggestion, how can you vote on that? How can the OP accept it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand If you are asking me specifically what I do when I see that: I don't upvote or downvote on those types of answers, I leave a comment pointing out why one of the suggestions is terrible. If the poster resolves it, I upvote. If not, I leave it alone and put faith in the possibility that somebody reading the answer will also read my comment and use their judgment. For accepting: I would take the same approach, if I were the OP.

Comment: @JasonC Not saying it's a bad idea to offer multiple ideas in a single answer, but it's not the norm, should not be expected, and when I do it (yes, I have done it) I usually do so [in an effort to show why one approach is better than the others, usually from a performance perspective](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19507/running-total-with-count/19509#19509), or [what the user can do with their current limitations, and what they will be able to do later when those limitations are lifted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261600/passing-in-a-large-string-of-guids/18264188#18264188).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh, and, closing thought; for the record, I do realize the value of specifics, and I do give specific answers. I just have an admittedly idealistic take on the world and believe people *should* be able to use a big picture view to solve their own problems. I try and encourage that view when possible; and discourage obsessions with specifics if I see it becoming problematic.

Comment: @JasonC I fail to see where obsessions with specifics are problematic. I see answers *every day* that seem like they are good answers but are bad for very specific, often-not-obvious reasons. Specifics are a good thing and should not be brushed aside.

Comment: I edited my wording at the same time you posted, because it was a poor choice.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's acceptable to add more than one answer to a question if ... you have more than one answer to a question.

If they're both helpful answers, why not?  This doesn't seem any different than answering a question once, describing two completely different methods.  That, and the SO engine allows it.  If it were undesirable to do this, it would be disallowed, right?

Or, if you answer a question, and then some time lateryou happen upon a better way to do it, then it would be reasonable to add another answer.  It would make interpretation of the upvotes less confusing (if anyone cares) because it would be clear that the upvotes were for the original answer, and not the original answer PLUS the answer you added later.

Comment: Good point about separating the upvotes. Usually when I have two separate answers I post them as one answer and try to point out the differences between them. I suppose, though, if they were *so* different that a comparison makes no sense, it would make sense to post two answers -- although that case may also indicate that the original question was too broad to remain on SO.

Comment: @JasonC as I commented above, I don't understand why that logic makes sense. If two independent people can post separate, different, but good answers, why couldn't one person do the same?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, it's a good point, and it's very gray. I feel like I haven't seen any questions on SO where there are two distinctly different good answers *and* the question is "appropriate" for SO -- but I also haven't been looking at answers that way (until now). Just to be clear though, I'm not pushing to disallow multiple answers or anything, just wondering about etiquette. I *do* feel strongly, though, that one person with two different answers could provide a *much* better answer by combining their two answers into one and highlighting the differences. :)

Comment: That is usually what I do, but I think it's just as valid to separate independent answers.