# Possibility to prioritize among your own answers to the same question

Tags: feature-request, multiple-answers

**Foreword:** This is a followup of my question [When you answer your own question with a preliminary and later final answer you can then accept NONE [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375929/) where I erred. It was not my own question. But I indeed gave two answers. And uncovered a scenario which should be discussed/addressed in regards of UX / platform-desirability.

### Scenario

- You give two answers.
- First a preliminary one.

  - This one has/may already be of some value.
  - Some people get involved with comments maybe.
- Later you gained more knowledge. And give a better or final answer.

### There seems to be consensus that giving more than one answer is legitimate

- It is technically possible as of 02/2022.
- Discussions on that practise which confirmed it as legit:
- 2013: [Are there any legitimate reasons for adding more than one answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193432/are-there-any-legitimate-reasons-for-adding-more-than-one-answer-to-a-question)
- 2009: [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice)

### Usability aspects currently unhandled

- Even though that the preliminary answer may be worse, it may be listed on top (e.g. because initial upvotes were good when there was more interest, or because of a higher comment count, I do not know the exact ranking mechanics)
- You have no way *to prioritize among your own answers*.
- This is an issue with questions with less interest/involvement (initially or at the time of the final answer)

  - You have to rely on the original poster coming back and accepting or upvoting your newer better final answer.
  - Or one of the few others involved (initially or meanwhile)
  - Which may not happen, b/c maybe the preliminary seems good enough
- You have to witness passively that your worse question is on top
- Or take matters in your own hand and delete the old preliminary answer. Which is bad for other reasons:

  - Destroys history/context.
  - Maybe disconnects some people who had "notification hooks" there.
  - Leaving a preliminary not necessarily wrong but mediocre answer on bottom has qualities for documenting "how to better not" (for external and internal search) for users who may err in the same paths.

Comment: What's wrong with editing the first answer then @ing the OP of the question to notify them of the improvement? (I'm aware on certain sites that there's the possibility of more than one valid answer so your proposal may still have merit there).

Comment: As I stated: Usually the community shall decide. But if the community is not involved, or only slowly, or not involved anymore, then that worse answer will remain. An example of where peer mechanisms may not work out optimally. And the author of the two answers has to standby and watch his/her worse question on top. Unbearable. And it is unlikely that you say: Ok, I give that 2-3weeks/months, then see if the community has self-corrected this. You are involved with it in a narrow time frame, and want to move it to "done". A good platform should not stand in the way of responsible answerer then.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Sorry: Only indirectly answered your proposal. Now on your proposal: Correcting the initial answer is suboptimal. Too much time elapsed. Comments all relate to the initial answer. Correcting that answer to your better/final answer which may be quite different, will make the whole discussion thread seem incomprehensible / out of context. There must be a solution for this with separate answers by the same person.

Comment: Comments aren't meant to last, and they're there to prompt clarification of a post so editing the post is just fine.

Comment: edit the old post and reply to the comments, if relevant, within the new answer. Posting two versions of the same answer is not optimal. Posting two completely different answers is legitimate when there can be more than one answer, e.g Worldbuilding, single-word-requests (EL&U), Puzzling, Meta etc. Posting an updated answer which resolves all the issues allows you to delete the obsolete, imperfect answer.

Comment: How many questions there are to which you have posted two answers? How many question have you seen that others have posted two answers?

Comment: If the second answer is a *refinement* of the first one, then I don't really see a reason for it to be separate. Yes, might be different but if it's taking clear steps from it, then I'd probably annotate with something like "At first thought <this> can be done but for <improvement reasons> it can be expanded into <new refined approach>". If the two are clearly different, then just post both and let the voting decide which one they prefer.

Comment: There is no such thing as a preliminary answer. A Preliminary answer sounds like an answer that should not be submitted since it’s incomplete. If an answer author says something is preliminary I am probably going to just downvote it

Comment: @VLAZ could you please post your comment into a standalone answer. I would like to accept it as the answer. It was the best answer to me.

Comment: @VLAZ I just see that Journeyman Geek 's answer is elder than yours and basically the same recommendation as yours.

Comment: @VLAZ I accepted Journeyman Geek 's answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On most sites, and in most situations you don't post two answers. You post one and in the process of answering, talk about both solutions and explain when one is better than the other. On a few sites, specifically *[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)*, you could post two stand-alone answers, but it is an exercise best left up to the reader to decide which works best for them.

As such, there isn't any need ever for a user to need to emphasise or prioritise one answer over another manually.

Comment: Multiple answers can work if they are not reliant on each other. Each can be voted on separately and there is little need to cross-compare them.

Comment: Well that's very site etiquette dependant but yes.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek. Good comprehensible answer! But the first sentence is an imperative and as such sounds very dogmatic. Not the style to build up a rationale IMHO. Please just rephrase it to "You usually don't post" or omit the sentence entirely. Because the rest very clearly makes a distinction and is good and very comprehensible. Should not be ruined by the strange tone of the 1st sentence. B/c it is a contradiction to start with "You don't. And only 2 sentences later mix in "but … you could …". Simply not coherent. Other than that very ok. Plan to accept after your correction, if you may.

Comment: And for all: Just encountered one example in the wild for another [good practise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789145/199400): **Edit your own answer to insert a recommendation with a link to the better answer** (someone else's or your own second answer) and then let the community decide on it. That's the best mix of "notifying readers/voters about your own preference" while still letting the community decide. Very humble I think. Even though on top, you openly show there's a seemingly better answer by someone else, and encourage to consider it. Evebtually the peers decide. Great mix!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks for rephrasing! Now a great answer. Accepted. 

Answer (score -5):

### UX Proposal 1: Keep the upvote/downvote mechanism but with a special "among my own answers" variation where appropriate

- If the current user has 2+ answers and then hovers over the upvote/downvote arrows on one of their answers, the hint text for it would say "Upvote within your own set of answers (3 total)" or "Downvote within your own set of answers (2 total)".
- Upon clicking the upvote or downvote arrows, you get a special dialog:

  > Note: You can never upvote your own answers in relation to other answers! But as you gave more than 1 answer to this question you can upvote/downvote within your own set of answers."
  >
  > [ ] Do not show this again
  >
  > [ Cancel ] [ Upvote among my answers]

Comment: Advantages of this design variant: No new UX patterns. Trying to upvote/downvote your own question is probably the most intuitive attempt to resolve the given situation. Anyhow the hint, dialog, and button wording then gives awareness of the special variation this is.

Answer (score -7):

UX Proposal 2: Introduce a special mechanism "Prioritize among my own answers"

Comment: Advantage: It is "its own thing" which the ranking algorithm can easily separate. Disadvantage: Too much attention for an edge case. Complicates UX. Higher learning curves for newcomers. Etc. I clearly am not in favor of this one. Just stated it here for completeness.